# How to limit the amount of users per license in intranet environment?

Tags: licensing, intranet

I'm developing a dev tool to be used in organization of different sizes. I want to be able to sell an organization licenses for n amount of computers and to prevent them from installing it on more machines than what they have payed for. If I have access to the internet the concept is fairly simple, I can create a public key and private key based on the motherboard serial number and have a web service that will limit the amount of keys produced. My problem is that some organizations are not connected to the internet and I want to be able to deal with this case as well. I could come up with a solution using a shared file on a shared folder that all users are validating against, but if possible I would prefer not to require the client to have a shared folder or deal with the bugs that could arise from a shared file everybody could temper with.
Any idea would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This how it works in Labs64 NetLicensing and might give you some ideas for your implementation:

- in "offline" enterprise intranet environment NetLicensing Agent is
  installed
- Agent can be still connected to the internet (DMZ) or receive entitlements via dongle/file transfer
- all product instances connecting to the Agent and being validated
- in the case new assets to be assigned to the enterprise - licenses transfer to be done from NetLicensing to Agent

I hope this will lead you to the right direction.

Comment: thanks a lot, I would appreciate if you could explain what is exactly an "agent".

Comment: In short: agent is a module which is beeing installed on customers premise and manages all acquired entitlements in offline mode:


`NetLicensing --> (offline) -> Agent <- (online / validation) -> Licensee / End-devices`